# Calculating ray intersection with two spheres (with smooth_blending between the two spheres)

Tags: geometry, interpolation, intersection-theory

I have the following function to define the distance to the interesection between a ray and the surface of a sphere:

```
float intersect_sphere_distance(Ray ray, Sphere sphere)
{
    // Calculate distance along the ray where the sphere is intersected
    float3 sphere_to_ray_start_vector = ray.origin - sphere.position;
    
    float hit_distance_1 = -dot(ray.direction, sphere_to_ray_start_vector);
    float hit_distance_2_sqr = hit_distance_1 * hit_distance_1 - dot(sphere_to_ray_start_vector, sphere_to_ray_start_vector) + sphere.radius * sphere.radius;
    
    if (hit_distance_2_sqr < 0)
        return 1.#INF; // Infinity
    
    float hit_distance_2 = sqrt(hit_distance_2_sqr);

    // Use entry point is not valid, use exit point
    return hit_distance_1 - hit_distance_2 > 0 ? hit_distance_1 - hit_distance_2 : hit_distance_1 + hit_distance_2;
}
```

And this function to determine the position in 3D space that a hit occured (this could be one of many sphere intersection tests to determine which sphere actually hit, hence the "best_hit" detail):

```
void intersect_sphere(Ray ray, inout RayHit best_hit, Sphere sphere)
{
    float hit_distance = intersect_sphere_distance(ray, sphere);
    
    if (hit_distance > 0 && hit_distance < best_hit.distance)
    {
        best_hit.distance = hit_distance;
        best_hit.position = ray.origin + hit_distance * ray.direction;
        
        best_hit.normal = normalize(best_hit.position - sphere.position);
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to do is write a function that smoothly blends between multiple spheres to make one consistant shape. The shape I wish to achieve is two spheres joined smoothly by a tube that tapers a little towards the centre.

I've seen this achieved when doing ray marching instead of using one infinite ray, but ultimately they tutorial found the distance to an object (or smoothly combined combinations of objects) and the rest should be roughly the same.

The video I first saw this on:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cp5WWtMoeKg&list=PLFt_AvWsXl0ehjAfLFsp1PGaatzAwo0uK&index=14

A snippet of his code where he does smooth blending, but I can't get it to work (I always get a shape that looks like only the intersecting volume between the spheres):

```
// polynomial smooth min (k = 0.1);
// from https://www.iquilezles.org/www/articles/smin/smin.htm
float4 Blend( float a, float b, float3 colA, float3 colB, float k )
{
    float h = clamp( 0.5+0.5*(b-a)/k, 0.0, 1.0 );
    float blendDst = lerp( b, a, h ) - k*h*(1.0-h);
    float3 blendCol = lerp(colB,colA,h);
    return float4(blendCol, blendDst);
}
```

This is what I've tried to do so far, with the commented out parts of the "smooth_..." functions being taken from the tutorial video, and the uncommented parts being from the linked github repo. The results are not good whichever I use. I either get both spheres intersecting normally with weird surface normals on one of them, or I get just the intersecting section with surface normals that look correct for the resulting shape at least, haha.

````
float smooth_lerp_amount(float a, float b, float k)
{
    // return max(k - abs(a-b), 0) / k;
    return saturate(0.5 + 0.5 * (b-a) / k);
}

float smooth_min(float a, float b, float k)
{
    // float h = max(k - abs(a-b), 0) / k;
    // return min(a, b) - pow(h, 3) * 1 / 6.0;

    float h = smooth_lerp_amount(a, b, k);
    return lerp(b, a, h) - k*h*(1.0-h);
}

void intersect_double_sphere(Ray ray, inout RayHit best_hit, Sphere sphere_a, Sphere sphere_b)
{    
    float hit_distance_a = intersect_sphere_distance(ray, sphere_a);
    float hit_distance_b = intersect_sphere_distance(ray, sphere_b);

    float hit_distance = smooth_min(hit_distance_a, hit_distance_b, 1.0f);
    
    if (hit_distance > 0 && hit_distance < best_hit.distance)
    {
        best_hit.distance = hit_distance;
        best_hit.position = ray.origin + hit_distance * ray.direction;
        
        float lerp_amount = smooth_lerp_amount(hit_distance_a, hit_distance_b, 1.0f);

        float3 normal_a = normalize(best_hit.position - sphere_a.position);
        float3 normal_b = normalize(best_hit.position - sphere_b.position);
        best_hit.normal = lerp(normal_a, normal_b, 1.0 - lerp_amount);
    }
}
```
````

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation) for "lerp" function.

Comment: I used lerp in a number of places in my code above. Also tried slerp in place of the calls to lerp just to see, and for things like the surface normal that's probably more accurate for my needs... But what I need is a way to calculate that I have hit a point that doesn't entirely sit on either either sphere, but somewhere in the smoothly connecting region between them. I guess half of my problem here is that I'm only doing anything with these conjoined shapes at all if it directly hits at least one